# derive class from a tuple

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates, template-templates

I have an std::tuple given like this:

```
typedef std::tuple<t1, t2, t3> tuple_t;
```

Now, I want to transform t3_tuple into a similar tuple:

```
typedef std::tuple< T<t1>, T<t2>, T<t3> > derived_tuple_t;
```

In my case, for example, `t1`, `t2`, and `t3` are primitives, and `T` is `std::stack`. In general, assume that that there might be `t4` and so on.

Of course, my second definition already solves the problem, but I'd like the deriving to be automatic: Given only `T` and `tuple_t`, build me `derived_tuple_t`. Like this:

```
template <class T, class tuple_t> using derived_tuple_t = std::tuple</*???*/>;
```

Is something like this possible? Maybe a short solution?

Comment: I think the question is not only `tuple` related, but applies to variadic templates in general.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A little partial specialization using template template parameters should do the job (generalized to variadic templates, not only tuples):

```
template<template<class...> class TT, class ArgsT>
struct make_over;

template<template<class...> class TT, template<class...> class ArgsT, class... Ts>
struct make_over<TT, ArgsT<Ts...>>{ using type = ArgsT<TT<Ts>...>; };

template<template<class...> class TT, class ArgsT>
using MakeOver = typename make_over<TT, ArgsT>::type;
```

Note that this can be problematic with stdlibs that don't use true variadic templates, and emulate it instead with macro machinery and default template arguments (like MSVC).

[Live example.](https://ideone.com/wyqNxY)

Comment: Can you please elaborate on why this might not work with MSVC? What does it mean that they do not use "true variadic templates"?

Comment: @Johannes: MSVC's stdlib uses `template<class T1 = _Nil, class T2 = _Nil, ...> class tuple;` and then partial specializations up to a certain limit to emulate variadic templates. A trait such as the above used on a `tuple<T1, T2>` will result in a `tuple<X<T1>, X<T2>, X<_Nil>, X<_Nil>...>` which will screw everything over.

Comment: is this a misbehavior of MSVC, which might be fixed by them in the future?

Comment: @Johannes: Sure, if they support variadic templates. :) The standard demands that tuple is implemented as `template<class... Args> class tuple;`.

Comment: Thanks! Do you see a solution without using the struct/class keywords at all?

Comment: @Johannes: You mean without any metafunction and only using-aliases? No, since no such functionality exists yet in the standard library.

Answer (score 4):

You could declare struct `update_tuple` with two template parameters:

1. `T` -  will be templated, and this parameter we will apply to the parameters in the `tuple`
2. `std::tuple` with a variable number of template parameters.

Then just create an alias for a new `tuple` with arguments applied with `T` using pack expansion

```
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>

template <template<class...> class, class>
struct update_tuple;

template <template <class...> class T, class... Args>
struct update_tuple<T, std::tuple<Args...>>
{
    using type = std::tuple<T<Args>...>;
};

int main()
{
    static_assert
    (
        std::is_same
        <
            std::tuple<std::vector<int>, std::vector<double>>,
            update_tuple<std::vector, std::tuple<int, double>>::type
        >::value,
        "They are not same"
    );
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks to @Xeo: Code will not fails if `T` could accept more than one template parameter(when others but first has defaults).

[Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=9528a9bb4ff34327ada29c671c45e9c8-cb489a3b6140cf059c41a6781910cb3e)

Comment: I think it would be nice to mention the word template template parameter and give some explanation...

Comment: @jogojapan, _"I think it would be nice to mention the word template template parameter"_ - would it? We do not use it anywhere.

Comment: @soon This is just an inductive declaration, right? Just for fun: Do you know if it is true to avoid the class keyword at all?

Comment: @soon: `template<class> class T` is a template, and as a parameter *of* a template, it's a *template template parameter*. :) Also note that your code will fail for class templates that take more than one argument, but have defaults for everyone but the first (like standard sequence containers).

Comment: @soon Not sure if I understand. But my point was that the answer seemed to consist only of code. I am in favor of answers that use language to explain things as well. You are obviously free to disagree.

Comment: @soon Accepted the other answer. It was more complete. Thanks, still!

Comment: @Johannes, No problems. I'm glad if my answer was helpful for you.

Comment: @Xeo, Not sure if I understand your first part correctly. Couldn't you check my answer again? Thanks anyway.

Comment: @soon: "Template template parameter" is just the name of the such a parameter (`T` in your case, and `TT` in mine).